# A command-line application that manages my lending accounts

Tags: python, console, finance

I'm learning Python and tried to solve a problem that I have. That problem is "managing" the people who owe me money. Basically, my project goal is:

- **v0.1** - command line application
- **v0.1.1** - command line application that works on persistent data
- **v1.0** - a (non web-base) GUI application that works on persistent data

I *think* I'm close to finishing **v0.1** so I'm looking for feedback before moving on. Here is the [Github Repo](https://github.com/alchermd/lending-manager/tree/5eed21e68ae004a4c84af611a001a0df3e4a7d68). From file structure, Python conventions, or even terms that I misused in the program itself, please do share your comments.

### Project Structure

```
.
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── main.py
└── modules
    ├── Account.py
    ├── Borrower.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── helpers.py
```

---

### `main.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
''' Main program '''

import os
import sys
from datetime import date
from modules.Borrower import Borrower
from modules.helpers import clear_delay, press_enter


def main():
    ''' The main function that allows the user to interact with the rest of the program. '''
    # Setup
    os.system("clear")
    database = {}

    # Greet the user.
    print("Good day! Welcome to our lending company!")
    clear_delay(1)

    # Ask for their name.
    print("What is your name? ", end='')
    name = input()
    clear_delay(1)

    # Name validation.
    if name in database:
        print("Welcome back, {}".format(name))
        clear_delay(1)
    elif name not in database:
        print("Name not found. Do you want to register? (Y/N)")
        user_wants_to_register = input().upper() == 'Y'
        clear_delay(2)

        if user_wants_to_register:
            database[name] = Borrower(name)
            print("You are now registered to our services, {}.".format(name))
            clear_delay(2)
        else:
            print("See you soon!")
            clear_delay(2)
            sys.exit()

    # Interface loop.
    choice = None
    while choice != 'Q':
        print("How may we help you?")
        print("[0]: Create a new account on my name.")
        print("[1]: Check accounts under my name.")
        print("[2]: Pay an existing account.")
        print("[Q]: Exit the program.")
        print("\nI want to: ", end='')

        choice = input().upper()
        clear_delay(1)

        # Account creation.
        if choice == '0':
            # Prompt for amount.
            print("How much will you borrow?")
            print("Amount: ", end='')
            amt = input()
            clear_delay(1)

            # Validate amount.
            if not amt.isdigit():
                print("Invalid value.")
                clear_delay(2)
                continue
            amt = float(amt)

            # Ask for a confirmation.
            print("A 5% interest rate will be applied weekly on this account.")
            print("Enter \"YES\" to confirm: ", end='')
            agree = input().upper() == "YES"
            clear_delay(1)

            if agree:
                database[name].open_account(amt, date.today(), 5)
                print("Account created! Summary: ")
                database[name].show_credits(-1)
                press_enter()

            else:
                continue

        # Check accounts.
        elif choice == '1':
            # Check if the user has no existing accounts.
            if not database[name].accounts:
                print("You have no accounts under your name.")
                clear_delay(2)

            else:
                print("Enter account id (leave blank to show all acounts): ", end='')
                acc_id = int(input())

                # Validate acc_id
                if acc_id == "":
                    database[name].show_credits()
                elif acc_id < 0 or acc_id >= len(database[name].accounts):
                    print("Invalid account id")
                    clear_delay(2)
                    continue
                else:
                    database[name].show_credits(int(acc_id))

                press_enter()

        # Pay account(s)
        elif choice == '2':
            # Check if the user has no existing accounts.
            if not database[name].accounts:
                print("You have no accounts under your name.")
                clear_delay(2)

            else:
                print("Here are your accounts:")
                database[name].show_credits()

                acc_id = int(press_enter("Enter account id to pay: "))

                # Validate acc_id
                if acc_id < 0 or acc_id >= len(database[name].accounts):
                    print("Invalid account id")
                    clear_delay(2)
                    continue

                else:
                    # Make payment
                    print("Enter amount to pay: ", end='')
                    amt = int(input())
                    database[name].pay(acc_id, amt)
                    clear_delay(2)

                    # Show feedback
                    print("Payment succeeded!")
                    database[name].show_credits(acc_id)
                    press_enter()

    print("Thank you for using our services. See you soon!")

main()
```

---

### `modules/Account.py`

```
''' Account module used for creating accounts. '''

import datetime

class Account:
    ''' Class used for Account objects. '''
    balance = 0
    interest = 0
    og_amount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, base_amount, start_date, int_rate):
        self.name = name
        self.og_amount = self.base_amount = base_amount
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.int_rate = int_rate * 0.01

        self.update_interest()
        self.update_balance()

    def show_info(self):
        ''' Prints the account information. '''
        print("Account: {}".format(self.name))
        print("Opened: {}".format(self.start_date))
        print("Statement: {} for {}% weekly interest.".format(self.og_amount, self.int_rate * 100))
        print("Interest: {}".format(self.interest))
        print("Current balance: {}".format(self.balance))

    def update_balance(self):
        ''' Calculates the balance of the account. '''
        self.balance = self.base_amount + self.interest

    def update_interest(self):
        ''' Calculates and updated the interest of the account. '''
        weeks_due = (datetime.date.today() - self.start_date).days // 7
        self.interest = self.base_amount * self.int_rate * weeks_due

    def pay(self, amount):
        ''' Reduces the account balance by amount an amount '''
        if amount > self.interest:
            self.interest, overflow = 0, self.interest - amount
            self.base_amount += overflow
        else:
            self.interest -= amount

        self.update_balance()
```

---

### `modules/Borrower.py`

```
''' Borrower module used for creating borrower objects. '''
from modules.Account import Account

class Borrower:
    ''' Borrower class creates a borrower object that can hold multiple accounts. '''
    accounts = []

    def __init__(self, name, credit_status=True):
        self.name = name
        self.credit_status = credit_status

    def open_account(self, base_amount, start_date, int_rate):
        ''' Adds an account object to the borrower's accounts list. '''
        if self.credit_status:
            self.accounts.append(Account(self.name, base_amount, start_date, int_rate))
        else:
            print("Bad credit status")

    def show_credits(self, index=None):
        ''' Shows the account information of the given index.
            Shows an error message if no accounts are opened.
            Shows all the accounts otherwise.
        '''
        if index is None:
            for account in self.accounts:
                print("-" * 10)
                print("ID: {}".format(self.accounts.index(account)))
                account.show_info()
        elif not self.accounts:
            print("No accounts opened")
        else:
            print("-" * 10)
            print("ID: {}".format(self.accounts.index(self.accounts[-1])))
            self.accounts[index].show_info()

    def pay(self, index, amount):
        ''' Pays an amount to the account at index. '''
        self.accounts[index].pay(amount)
```

---

### `modules/helpers.py`

```
''' Utility functions '''

import os
import time

def clear_delay(secs):
    ''' Delays execution of the program and then clears the screen afterwards. '''
    time.sleep(secs)
    os.system("clear")

def press_enter(msg="Press enter to continue"):
    ''' Delays execution of the program and then clears the screen when enter is pressed.
        An optional msg can be passed as an argument to customize the output.
        The keyboard input is returned.
    '''
    print("-" * 10)
    print(msg, end='')
    output = input()
    os.system("clear")

    return output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's more a better user interface than clean code, but why ask user if they already registered if u would register them or close program anyway? Always haven't liked that in websites. Signing or register should be one button.

```
def sigin_or_register(users):
    print('Signin or register: ')
    name = input()
    if name in users:
        print("Welcome back, {}".format(name))
    else:
        print("You are now registered to our services, {}.".format(name))
```

As to the code I'll will review it a bit later, but this long `if else` should be refactored into a list or a dictionary of possible action functions like `[action1, action2, action3]`.

```
def create_account(accounts, user):
    try:
        amt = prompt('How much will you borrow?\nAmount: ', int)
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid Value')
        # Ask for a confirmation.
        print('A 5% interest rate will be applied weekly on this account.')
        agree = prompt('Enter "YES" to confirm', lambda i: i.upper() == 'YES')
        if agree:
            accounts[user].open_account(amt, date.today(), 5)
            print('Account created! Summary: ')
            accounts[user].show_credits(-1)
            press_enter()


def prompt(string, as_type=None, delay=1):
    print(string, end='')
    inp = input()
    clear_delay(delay)
    if as_type and inp = '':
        return None
    return as_type(inp)


def check_accounts(accounts, users):
    if not accounts[user].accounts:
        print('You have no accounts under your user.')
        clear_delay(2)
    else:
        acc_id = prompt('Enter account id (leave blank to show all acounts): ', int)

        if acc_id is None:
            database[user].show_credits()
        try:
            database[users].show_credits(acc_id)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Invalid accout id')
        press_enter()


def exit():
    print("Thank you for using our services. See you soon!") 
    sys.exit()


actions = (
    ('0', (create_account, 'Create a new account on my name'),
    ('1', (check_accounts, 'Check accounts under my name'),
    ('Q', (exit, 'Exit the program')),
)
    choice = None
    print("How may we help you?")
    actions = OrderedDict(actions)
    choices_prompt = '\n'.join(f'[{key}]: {hint}' for key, (action, hint), actions.items())
    while True:
        choice = prompt('How may we help you?\n' + choices_prompt, str.upper)
        action, key = actions[choice]
        action(accounts, user)
```

Notice also the `prompt` function refactoring. This code may not work, but it shows the idea.

Comment: I updated `main.py` in the original post. What do you mean by "this long if else should be refactored into a list or a dictionary of possible action functions like `[action1, action2, action3]`" ?

Comment: @John I've updated the answer.